# Is it possible to protect my JPasswordField against keyloggers

Tags: java, security, applet, keylogger, jpasswordfield

I'm writing a small applet with a JPasswordField, and I'd like to know if it's possible to protect the content of my JPasswordField, in case where the user's PC is hacked by a keylogger ...

I know that Java cannot do kernel level operations, so impossible to encrypt user's keystrocks. Is there eventually other alternative solutions please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: a keylogger is just that, it reads keystrokes. It doesn't read output from a textfield.

Comment: I see you edited your post after my initial comment. If it's that sensitive provide your users and on screen keyboard so they can click on the letters / numbers instead of having to key them in. I would submit this as an answer but most likely it would be -20 in 2 minutes

Comment: What does the password do?  E.G. unlock some functionality in the applet, log-in to a DB..

Comment: Like Green Day says, the only way to protect against a keylogger is by an OSK, and for added security, randomized placement of letters. However, users hate having to use them.

Comment: What is a keylogger?  According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging it is "the action of tracking (or logging) the keys struck on a keyboard, typically in a covert manner so that the person using the keyboard is unaware that their actions are being monitored" - I don't think there is any practical software based solution.  ***You could require your users to perform some Diffie-Hellman calculation in their head, but that is not practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe so as key loggers work via OS hooks, something your applet won't be able to get near to. Shoot, even a desktop Java application would have a tough time doing something like this and would require native code if it were possible at all.

Comment: if key loggers include devices ađded to the keyboard, native code is inadequate.

Comment: @emory: Yep. Native code would work for simple key loggers, but not much more. That's why the "if it were possible at all" statement in my post above. But the OP is adding one more layer of impossibility due an applet's sandbox layer, lowering his possibility of success to the ridiculously small.